# Why a recursion error occurs when implementing the Karachuba algorithm in python

Tags: python, karatsuba, infinite-recursion

Karachuba algorithm : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm

```
threshold = 4


def prod2(a, b):
    n = max(len(str(a)), len(str(b)))
    if a == 0 or b == 0:
        return
    elif n <= threshold:
        return a*b

    else:
        m = n/2
        x = a/pow(10, m)
        y = a % pow(10, m)
        w = b/pow(10, m)
        z = b % pow(10, m)
        r = prod2(x+y, w+x)
        p = prod2(x, w)
        q = prod2(y, z)
        return p*pow(10, 2*m) + (r-p-q)*pow(10, m)+q


a = 12314124
b = 123123
print(prod2(a, b))
```

`RecursionError`: maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object

I have implemented the Karachuba algorithm in Python and return it appropriately depending on the input value, but I don't know why the recurtion error occurs.

Comment: you are returning null

Comment: The `/` in `x = a/pow(10, m)` is performing floating division. You need to use the `//` integer division operator, there and elsewhere. That's probably not your only bug